# jQuery Validation: How to take down the check marks after the form is submitted (ajax submission)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form (for editing existing info) whose submission is done in ajax via jQuery's $.post(). Prior to the submission, jQuery Validation kicks in to make sure the values that got changed are valid and generate a check mark beside each valid one.

My problem is that the check marks don't go away after submission. I tried the validator method, resetForm(), which took down the check marks but having the undesirable side-effect of reverting all changed inputs back to their old values.

Is there a way to only remove the check marks?

Is there a way to update the original values memorized by resetForm()? If so, then I could use resetForm() to achieve my purpose without the undesirable side-effect.

Please help. Thank you all.

**Clarification:** When I say "check mark" it's not the same as checkbox. As a matter of fact, my question has nothing to do with checkbox. To see what I am referring to as check mark, go to [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) and type in some valid string into one of the text inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "check marks" in the [demo you linked to](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) are the result off CSS styling, after the class "checked" was added to the `<label>` within the `<td class="status">`, when the associated input was considered valid. A class is added to the label, which gives it a checkmark background.

Anyways, to trigger some behavior when the form is submitted, use the `submitHandler`. Example:

```
$('form').validate({
    // Your config here...
    submitHandler: function() {
        $('label').removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```

It's all customized in that demo, so you'll have to do what works with ***your*** setup and options.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through jQuery.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').removeAttr('checked')
```

Ah, I may have misunderstood your question. Just find the class for those check marks and set them to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: What if some of the checkboxes are supposed to be checked by default?

Comment: He did mention remove all check marks, but I guess I'm referring to the wrong check marks, not the ones on the checkbox.

Comment: You can add an additional attribute e.g. 'default' to identify checkboxes that are checked by default. Then filter them out from your selector
`$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:not([default])').removeAttr('checked')`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to grab the form values after validation but before submission and repopulate after submit.

```
var backup = $('#form-id').serializeArray();
$('#form-id').resetForm();

//
// submit logic
//

$.each(backup, function(key, value) {
   $('[name="' + key + '"]').val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just like input text fields have `element.defaultValue`, checkboxes have `checkboxObject.defaultChecked` which is a bool value and can easily be applied with JQuery using the `attr()` function.  The `prop()` function is recommended for properties such as "checked", "disabled", "selected", etc., but you check the box with

```
$('#mybox').prop('checked');
```

For a form reset function you'd probably rather use something like

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked',$(this).defaultChecked);
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_defaultchecked.asp